# Bad alloc in vector.resize()

Tags: c++, visual-studio, allocation, bad-alloc

I tried the following C++ codein Visual Studio 2017 (Community version):

```
vector <int> V;
V.resize(600000000);
for (int i = 0;i < 600000000;i++)
{
    if (i % 10000000 == 0)cout << i << endl;
}
```

but got:

exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location

I changed Heap Reserve Size, Heap Commit Size, Stack Reserve Size and Stack Commit Size in Propeties (of project)->Linker->System do huge: 1000000000. Also, I changed "Total paging file size for all drives" to 100GB RAM (I have virtual machine with 120GB RAM) in Control Panel. It didn't worked.

Is there some way to be able to put more than 600000000 integers to vector then?

Comment: Are you compiling in 32bits or 64bits?

Comment: And it's not a stack problem, don't modify the default values there, it's a heap problem because you try to allocate more than 2GB.

Comment: You set the heap size to 1 GB and then you try to allocate more than 2 GB ?

Comment: Worked on my machine.  600,000,000 x sizeof(int) ==> 4,800,000,000 bytes (on my machine).  Maybe your 1,000,000,000 heap size isn't big enough on your machine.

Comment: Here is a question: What problem are you really trying to solve?  Why do you need so much memory allocated?

Comment: In case you have C++14 or later you might consider adding some digit separators into such huge numbers to make them more readable, like so: `600'000'000`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are compiling a 64-bit binary, not 32-bit.

600.000.000 integers are 2.400.000.000 bytes (~2gb), which is too much for a 32bit binary by default.

If you require more than 2gb in 32bit binary, you can link using the [/LARGEADDRESSAWARE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wz223b1z.aspx) flag in Visual Studio

Edit: As mentioned by [Deduplicator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3204551/deduplicator), the flag probably won't make this example work in 32bit. The best solution is to build a 64bit binary.

Comment: But even `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` probably won't lead to having such a big consecutive chunk of the address-space (more than half for 32bit) available.

Comment: 32-bit apps can't have a 2 GB single allocation. It isn't possible because there are holes in the memory map which Windows *will not* allow you to cross through.